# Reading Regular Expression

Tags: regex, matlab, yaml

For my project I need to read yaml file. Below is the structure of the file.

```
features: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 2772
   dt: f
   data: [ 1.54081415e-02, 2.49357540e-02, 4.28411551e-02,
       3.20738047e-01, 3.57459992e-01, 1.28003284e-01, 4.50998023e-02,
       5.17182751e-03, 1.32489363e-02, 3.99506558e-03, 3.16332430e-02,
       4.81718145e-02, 2.60532290e-01, 3.57459992e-01, 9.07626748e-02,
       2.67604515e-02, 6.93456084e-03, 2.79696658e-03, 8.11475739e-02,
       6.37108535e-02, 5.64115569e-02, 2.03206182e-01, 3.57459992e-01,
       1.62178174e-01, 1.15586087e-01, 1.01212829e-01, 1.30639806e-01,
       9.16789323e-02, 9.83756483e-02, 1.13223732e-01, 3.16813707e-01,
       3.57459992e-01, 1.09362096e-01, 8.66392106e-02, 4.11560647e-02]
```

Can someone help to read data values in matlab using regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this

```
pattern = '/[\d.e-]*\S/';
regexp(data, pattern, 'match');
```

and after that you can access it like this

```
data[1], data[2]...
```

to get familiar with it more, read **[here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html)**